# Python: How to use a String Index ( '[0][1][0]' ) as the Index for a multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, eval

I want to use a String: `'[0][1][0]'` as the Index for a multidimensional Array. If I write the Code `myarray[0][1][0]` I get the Content from the first Child of the First Item and it's second Child ( `[0][1][0]` ).

That still works:

```
myarray = [
            [
              'child 0',
              [
                'child 0,0',
                [
                  'child 0,0,0'
                ]
                'child 0,1',
                [
                  'child 0,1,0'
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              'child 1',
              [
                'child 1,0',
                'child 1,1'
              ],
            [
              'child 2',
              [
                'child 2,0'
              ]
            ]
          ]
print myarray[0][1][0] # >> prints: "child 0,1,0"
```

That doesn't work for sure:

```
# use same array as above (myarray)
sindex='[0][1][0]'
print myarray[sindex] # should print: "child 0,1,0" but results in "KeyError: '[0][1][0]'"
```

**Edit:**

As learned from the Comments below ( thanks guys ! ) it's important to know that the `sindex`can vary in length like `'[1][0][2]'` or `'[2][1][4][2][0]'`.

**Edit II:**

As i figured out it's not that easy to mutate *Brian's* Solutions

```
def get_index_from_string(arr, idx_string):
    i = [int(i) for i in idx_string[1:-1].split('][')]
    res = arr[:]
    for x in i:
        res = res[x]
    return res
```

to be able to remove the Item from the array with `myarray[0][1].pop(0)` he is just spitting out the Nodes Value and not pointing to it. A Solution could be to rebuild the Array by ieterating it but that's impossible because it inherits multiple different Types I have to parse then to rebuild a Copy exactly without the Node Brian's function find.

Also *Leon's* Solution

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
reduce(operator.getitem, sindex, myarray)
```

I have no ideo how to transform this with `Reduce` to a `pop()`Solution.

Comment: But Why @Dirk ?

Comment: This seems like a bit of an XY problem(you ask how to fix your solution instead of how to solve your problem). Where are you getting the string from in the first place?

Comment: @ZdaR: because the length of the sindex can vary. Eg. `'[0]'`or `[0][1]'`

Comment: @leaf, you are absolutly right! I try to get a solution instead of overthinking the real Issue here. I have an Multi Array with different Dimensions and sizes. And the Index-String can vary in length. And what I have to solve is to remove special Childs from the Array with `myarray[0][1].pop(0)` to remove the `[0][1][0]` Item. In another Iteration I have to remove `[1][0][0][2][0]` for example.

Comment: @DirkSchiller Alright. You should add that information to the question however, as it is hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely seems like an XY problem: how did the indexes end up being in a string in the first place? It looks to me like you could store that information in a better way.

There is certainly no built-in function to parse a string representing the index. I suggest parsing the indexes out of the string first and then proceeding as normal.

For a two-dimensional list, this could look like the following:

```
>>> my_array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> sindex = '[1][0]'
>>> y, x = [int(i) for i in sindex[1:-1].split('][')]
>>> my_array[y][x]
3
```

Alternatively, you could use `eval`, but [`eval` is evil](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), so I won't show you how to do that.

EDIT:

If you need a function that can handle variable length, try the following. (Again, the actual problem is probably upstream.) This function is pretty ugly, taking a copy of the original array:

```
>>> def get_index_from_string(arr, idx_string):
...     i = [int(i) for i in idx_string[1:-1].split('][')]
...     res = arr[:]
...     for x in i:
...         res = res[x]
...     return res
...
>>> my_arr = [1, 2, 3]
>>> my_arr2 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> my_arr3 = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
>>> get_index_from_string(my_arr, '[1]')
2
>>> get_index_from_string(my_arr2, '[1][0]')
3
>>> get_index_from_string(my_arr3, '[1][0][1]')
6
```

Comment: Hey Brian, I know about ev(i)l and I know it's a bad solution. The problem I have to solve is that the Index String can vary in length. Eg. `'[0][1]'` or `'[1][0][1]'`

Comment: @DirkSchiller Edited accordingly

Comment: The part with the `res = res[x]` is amazing. You still going down the path exactly to the Position where the String-Index is pointing to. Great work!